# Is there a way to make a Typescript key optional based on a condition in a generic type?

Tags: typescript

I would like to create a generic TS type that given an existing interface returns an interface that makes all last-level properties optional so given the following type

```
interface FormDeep {
    email: string;
    address: {
        street: {
            line1: string;
            line2: string;
        }
        town: string;
    }
}
```

this type should be valid

```
const newAddress: DeepPartialLastLevel<FormDeep> = {
    email: undefined,
    address: {
        street: {
            line1: undefined,
            line2: undefined
        },
        town: undefined,  
    }
}
```

but this one should not

```
const newAddressNotValid: DeepPartialLastLevel<FormDeep> = {
    email: undefined,
    address: {
        street: undefined, // street is not last level so it should be mandatory
        town: undefined,  
    }
}
```

I have successfully created a type that does that

```
type DeepPartialLastLevel<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends object ? DeepPartialLastLevel<T[K]> : (T[K] | undefined)
}
```

The problem arises when I want the  key to not be specified at all (VS being defined and equal to `undefined`).

To summarize: I want the following object to be valid

```
const newAddress2: DeepPartialLastLevel<FormDeep> = {
    email: undefined,
    address: { // TS complains because town is missing
        street: {
            line1: undefined,
            line2: undefined
        },
    }
}
```

I need the property to be optional based on the condition `T[K] extends object` something like

```
[K in keyof T as T[K] extends object? [K]: [K]?]: T[K] extends object ? DeepPartialLastLevel<T[K]> : T[K]
```

but this is not valid from a TS syntax point of view

I have created [a simple TS playground to reproduce](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=47&ssc=19&pln=47&pc=88#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHsoFsAiEIAOyA3gFDIXIRZzAA2AXMgM5hSgDmA3OZXACb8oEZsyZlKklm3xhxvKVLqgIARiat2IbgsWVlICACYNbTjz3IAvrslh0AdxCmtOyTZukvCdCFbJDBwBBQWFRADl0MAA1OGV+JjxCAAU4KDBgOIAZOFYsiAA3CDoAHgxsJIIAPmQAXhJdalpGZABXEH4IGBV+ABpdASERMQbLTVkmds7uwz7bSnsnSY6unt6KXQ8vAHpt5AAVAAtgZmRfFGZD9Fa6fmQAIxQCuOB+Uh8-MACIYNDhxPwBFS6UydByeUKxTKmFwgJq9QklCa9GW0zWAz+onkYxkEDko0s+hU6jaKxmEDmhKJhhMpLRs3mFCs-Usi2cdNWs3WyE2pE8uyOJzOhhYVxudzizHQDyeLze718-kCISGolplWBGWyuTA+SKpXKsMI8IJFGRLSmnIpLL4mJGiMU4zx2KpyAMalRVsprvdtMt5LelmZvM8YAAngQUBq0lqwTq9VD9ibEQBtADSyFAyAA1hAw+gYAcALpMfbpotUAAekA6p3Q9wAVhAEF8APzIaMg7UQ-UlMtpos1JgACn7FYAPhyAwBKPlAA)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mqxKkN) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am i missing?

Comment: yes this looks like it is working, I'd be glad to have an explanation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm:

- Loop through only objects fields and recursively call the type for them
- Loop through the rest of the fields and mark them optional
- Return an intersection of object fields and non-object fields

To loop through the fields, we are going to use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html), and to filter out the fields we need to use [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as). Basically, if the field is not an object we make its key `never`, which removes the field completely:

```
type DeepPartialLastLevel<T> = {
    [K in keyof T as T[K] extends object ? K : never]: DeepPartialLastLevel<T[K]>
}
```

Using [infer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) keyword we are going to store the result of the previous mapped type in the inferred type `OnlyObjects`:

```
type DeepPartialLastLevel<T> = {
    [K in keyof T as T[K] extends object ? K : never]: DeepPartialLastLevel<T[K]>
} extends infer OnlyObjects
? // do something
: never // in theory will be reached
```

Now, again we are going to use `mapped types` to map through the object's keys excluding keys of the `OnlyObjects`, which is done using built-in utility type [Exclude](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers), and to mark them optional we are going to use `?` [optional property modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#property-modifiers):

```
{
   [K in Exclude<keyof T, keyof OnlyObjects>]?: T[K];
}
```

Getting everything together:

```
type DeepPartialLastLevel<T> = {
    [K in keyof T as T[K] extends object ? K : never]: DeepPartialLastLevel<T[K]>
} extends infer OnlyObjects
    ? OnlyObjects & {
        [K in Exclude<keyof T, keyof OnlyObjects>]?: T[K];
    }
    : never;
```

The excluding part can be also done using the built-in utility type [Partial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) and [Omit](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys):

```
type DeepPartialLastLevel<T> = {
    [K in keyof T as T[K] extends object ? K : never]: DeepPartialLastLevel<T[K]>
} extends infer OnlyObjects
    ? OnlyObjects & Partial<Omit<T, keyof OnlyObjects>>
    : never;
```

Either of them work as expected.

Testing:

```
interface FormDeep {
    email: string;
    address: {
        street: {
            line1: string;
            line2: string;
        };
        town: string;
    };
}

const newAddressNotValid: DeepPartialLastLevel<FormDeep> = {
    email: undefined,
    address: {
        street: undefined,
        town: undefined,
    },
};

// This one should be valid
const newAddress: DeepPartialLastLevel<FormDeep> = {
    email: undefined,
    address: {
        street: {
            line1: undefined,
            line2: undefined,
        },
        town: undefined,
    },
};

//This one should also be valid
const newAddress2: DeepPartialLastLevel<FormDeep> = {
    email: undefined,
    address: {
        street: {
            line1: undefined,
            line2: undefined,
        },
    },
};
```

[Link to Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHsoFsAiEIAOyA3gFDIXIRZzAA2AXMgM5hSgDmA3OZXACb8oEZsyZlKklm3xhxvKVLqgIARiat2IbgsWVlICACYNbTjz3IAvhb1h0AdxCmtOyTdJXSpBOhCtkQwcAQUFhUQA5dDAANThlfiY8QgAFOCgwYHiAGThWbIgANwg6AB4MbGSCAD5kAF4SXWpaRmQAVxB+CBgVfgAaXQEhETFGy01ZJg6unsN+3Ul7JynO7t6B9wGPUgB6HeQAFQALYGZkPxRmI-Q2un5kACMUQvjgfh8-AKDQ4dEk-AIaQyWTouXyRRK5UwuABtQaEkozXoKxm60GYRG8nGMggcjGln0KnU7VWswg8wJhMMJhJqLmGz0VgZiiWzlpa3puiZnh4ux2x1O50MLGut3u8WY6Eez1e718-jAgQgIQxohpVSBmRyeTABWKZQqMMIcPxFCRrWmHPJzOQQ3CowRigmuKxlOQBjUKKtFLdHpplrJPsU3M2PO8YAAngQUBr0lrQTq9ZCDibHcgANoAaWQoGQAGsIBH0DBDrazgcswBdKgAD0gnTO6AeACsIAhFQB+ZDZpiGYpQSv-VJxkFg3UQsoVzOV6qeWv1-hnUAwaDIADyIDoEbXLbbYGYui7G63O9b7bOADJkJqQaU11hgGBSgc+vnC8X15vt7vz9VZ5JewhKAeCAA)